# Can't launch script with keyboard shortcut

Tags: bash, scripts, shortcut-keys

I'm trying to bind a script (script1) that starts another script (script2) to a keyboard shortcut, but it doesn't seem to actually start the second script.

The first script is supposed to kill the second script if it is already running and then restart it:

```
#! /bin/bash
killall -e script2.sh
/home/user/script2.sh
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and gnome 3.36.8. The scripts are working when I manually start them from the terminal.

Could anybody help me please?

Comment: How are you trying and in what desktop environment? How do we know the scripts are correct?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and gnome 3.36.8. The scripts are working when I manually start them from the terminal.

Comment: Fine, please add the info on your system to the question: this is relevant information because assigning keyboard shortcuts is different between desktops.